# Shortening the content of my website homepage

Tags: seo

I have a technology related website with Domain Authority 50+ and above 3 Million monthly visits. I’m thinking to shorten the content of my website homepage to make it more user centric. For most of the main industry keywords home page of the website is ranking good. Will shorting the content hamper my website ranking (Homepage and other pages) or any negative impact considering the SEO?

Comment: This is a little broad, can you add some details that will help users be able to provide specific answers?

Comment: I agree. For example, we do not know the size of your page, whether the page is huge, large, or full of fluff writing that can be safely redacted, or how relational it is to your other content, or anything. As it is, we would be pulling opinions out of the air from hither and yonder.

Answer (score 3):

Good practice says you shouldn't have less than 300 words per page. If you are shortening your content, but keeping it above the 300 word minimum you should be ok.
There are many other elements involved in SEO, not just quantity of content, so you need to take a holistic approach.